# how to know all django reverse lookups pointing to a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model A, and several models (B, C and D), all of them with a foreign field pointing to A. I want to implement a method to collect all records in B, C, and D related to each record in A, through the reverse look ups set in foreign keys in B, C and D.

The problem is that the amount of models with a foreign key pointing to A can change, so I want to make the method dynamic, so I need to know the models and their fields pointing at A, and their `related_name`.

Is there a way to obtain this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Meta class of the model to get a list of all the fields and filter them to get only the reverse relations.

```
def get_reverse_lookup_fields(model: models.Model):
    return [
        field
        for field in model._meta.get_fields()
        if field.auto_created and not field.concrete
    ]
```

[Here are the field attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-attribute-reference) you can check for, and [here is the Meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model)